# What are the most common spelling errors on the Webmasters site?

Tags: discussion, cleanup

What are the most common spelling errors can be corrected across the site? How would one help edit spelling corrections?

Comment: Related: [Example domain cleanup](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1222/example-domain-cleanup)

Answer (score 2):

I ran a spell checker across the entire site.  Here are the all the words it found that were misspelled at least 100 times:

| Count | Misspelling | Suggestion | Reason |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4045 | url | URL | Capitalization |
| 2031 | Wordpress | WordPress | Capitalization |
| 1767 | urls | URLs | Capitalization |
| 1721 | javascript | JavaScript | Capitalization |
| 1661 | https | HTTPS | Capitalization |
| 1648 | html | HTML | Capitalization |
| 1294 | htaccess | .htaccess | Punctuation |
| 1282 | wordpress | WordPress | Capitalization |
| 1280 | http | HTTP | Capitalization |
| 1189 | php | PHP | Capitalization |
| 1149 | apache | Apache | Capitalization |
| 959 | Adsense | AdSense | Capitalization |
| 953 | Javascript | JavaScript | Capitalization |
| 872 | css | CSS | Capitalization |
| 843 | URL's | URLs | Punctuation |
| 759 | seo | SEO | Capitalization |
| 744 | adsense | AdSense | Capitalization |
| 698 | ok | OK | Capitalization |
| 695 | CloudFlare | Cloudflare | Capitalization |
| 677 | ip | IP | Capitalization |
| 605 | facebook | Facebook | Capitalization |
| 531 | nginx | Nginx | Capitalization |
| 521 | Adwords | AdWords | Capitalization |
| 441 | dns | DNS | Capitalization |
| 414 | js | JS | Capitalization |
| 395 | [dont](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%22dont%22) | don't | Apostrophe |
| 391 | h1 | H1 | Capitalization |
| 386 | Godaddy | GoDaddy | Capitalization |
| 367 | cpanel | cPanel | Capitalization |
| 339 | googlebot | Googlebot | Capitalization |
| 336 | pagerank | PageRank | Capitalization |
| 326 | URLS | URLs | Capitalization |
| 318 | godaddy | GoDaddy | Capitalization |
| 307 | ajax | AJAX | Capitalization |
| 292 | i'm | I'm | Capitalization |
| 291 | [StackOverflow](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%22StackOverflow%22) | Stack Overflow | Spacing |
| 267 | Paypal | PayPal | Capitalization |
| 265 | english | English | Capitalization |
| 255 | xml | XML | Capitalization |
| 251 | linux | Linux | Capitalization |
| 235 | Youtube | YouTube | Capitalization |
| 230 | cloudflare | Cloudflare | Capitalization |
| 225 | youtube | YouTube | Capitalization |
| 224 | ssl | SSL | Capitalization |
| 216 | [StackExchange](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%22StackExchange%22) | Stack Exchange | Spacing |
| 216 | mysql | MySQL | Capitalization |
| 210 | adwords | AdWords | Capitalization |
| 206 | IP's | IPs | Punctuation |
| 205 | Github | GitHub | Capitalization |
| 203 | 404's | 404s | Punctuation |
| 189 | api | API | Capitalization |
| 187 | GoogleBot | Googlebot | Capitalization |
| 180 | bing | Bing | Capitalization |
| 178 | CPanel | cPanel | Capitalization |
| 176 | Ok | OK | Capitalization |
| 164 | [doesnt](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%22doesnt%22) | doesn't | Apostrophe |
| 163 | [thats](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%22thats%22) | that's | Apostrophe |
| 160 | github | GitHub | Capitalization |
| 158 | SERPS | SERPs | Capitalization |
| 158 | jquery | jQuery | Capitalization |
| 150 | Pagerank | PageRank | Capitalization |
| 149 | [seperate](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%22seperate%22) | separate | Spelling |
| 140 | Cloudfront | CloudFront | Capitalization |
| 138 | phpmyadmin | phpMyAdmin | Capitalization |
| 138 | paypal | PayPal | Capitalization |
| 138 | Hostgator | HostGator | Capitalization |
| 136 | pdf | PDF | Capitalization |
| 136 | [de](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%22de%22) |  | Unknown |
| 135 | Cpanel | cPanel | Capitalization |
| 130 | 301's | 301s | Punctuation |
| 129 | h2 | H2 | Capitalization |
| 127 | joomla | Joomla | Capitalization |
| 125 | cms | CMS | Capitalization |
| 124 | url's | URLs | Punctuation |
| 124 | [stackoverflow](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%22stackoverflow%22) | Stack Overflow | Spacing |
| 124 | firefox | Firefox | Capitalization |
| 122 | Dreamhost | DreamHost | Capitalization |
| 118 | apache2 | Apache2 | Capitalization |
| 117 | drupal | Drupal | Capitalization |
| 116 | wikipedia | Wikipedia | Capitalization |
| 115 | i've | I've | Capitalization |
| 113 | png | PNG | Capitalization |
| 107 | [se](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%22se%22) |  | Unknown |
| 106 | html5 | HTML5 | Capitalization |
| 104 | Mediawiki | MediaWiki | Capitalization |
| 104 | [Im](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%22Im%22) | I'm | Apostrophe |
| 104 | blogspot | Blogspot | Capitalization |
| 100 | vps | VPS | Capitalization |
| 100 | [stackexchange](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%22stackexchange%22) | Stack Exchange | Spacing |

#### Methodology

1. [Download the entire Stack Exchange data dump](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) which takes several hours using its torrent, even with a fast internet connection.
2. Run the spell checker against the entire archive.  The way it works is:

   1. Parses rows out of the data dump that contain `Title=` and `Body=` XML elements.
   2. Parses the Markdown in the body and discards code blocks, HTML tags, URLs, and links.
   3. Breaks the title and the remaining text from the body into words.
   4. Compares the words to the aspell dictionary and discards any that are spelled correctly.
   5. Compares the words to a [dictionary of technical terms, tech product names, and jargon that is used on the Stack Exchange network](https://github.com/stephenostermiller/Stack-Exchange-Auto-Editor/blob/master/stack-exchange-words.txt) and discards any such words.
   6. Pipes the remaining misspellings to be counted.
   7. Adds spelling suggestions from a [spelling corrections list](https://github.com/stephenostermiller/Stack-Exchange-Auto-Editor/blob/master/spelling-corrections.txt)
   8. Formats the output in a Markdown table

   The command for running it produce the table output above is: `7zcat /stackexchange/webmasters.stackexchange.com.7z | grep Body= | node editor.user.js stack-exchange-words | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -n 500 | node editor.user.js print-correction | grep -E '^[0-9]{3}' | sed -E 's/^([^\|]*\| )([^\|]*)( .*(Spelling|Apostrophe|Spacing|Unknown))$/\1[\2](https:\/\/webmasters.stackexchange.com\/search?tab=votes\&q=%22\2%22)\3/g;s/(.*)/| \1 |/g'`

#### Editing to correct spelling

Any user to our site can edit submit edits to any post. Spelling corrections are welcome. Users with enough reputation can make edits without any review, however edits from low reputation users need to be approved.

I have written a user script that can correct many of these spelling errors (and correct other types of errors as well) with the touch of a button: [Auto-Editor: a user script for automatically correcting common errors](https://stackapps.com/questions/9440/auto-editor-a-user-script-for-automatically-correcting-common-errors)

As with all clean-up projects, don't just fix this one issue. More than likely there are other issues with the post that should be addressed.  Edits should be rejected in the edit queue unless they attempt to fix **all** the major problems in a given post.  That may include:

- Non-descriptive titles
- Capitalization
- Formatting

  - Paragraph breaks
  - Lists
  - Code blocks
- Other misspellings
- Grammar
- Tags (either inappropriate or missing)
- Remove "hi", "thanks", "please help", "here is my question", and signatures

Be aware of front-page flooding. **Only fix a few posts at a time**.  It usually takes a while to edit each post properly, so you won't want to do to many of them at once anyway.

It is also common that posts that have spelling errors should be closed.  If the post is:

- unclear
- duplicate
- a site review or other problem that no other webmaster will encounter
- asks for third party tools (or other off-site resources)

flag the post to be closed.

Comment: Dang, I've _always_ written "StackOverflow" and "StackExchange" as one word!? (The one word spelling would seem to be the most _common_ spelling on Webmasters and StackOverflow.)

Comment: Awesome effort btw! :)

Comment: You don't seem to be able to search for _Capitalization_ issues using the standard search box?

Comment: Unfortunately site search is always case insensitive so I didn't link any of the capitalization errors to site search

Comment: You have too much time on your hands @StephenOstermiller :o)  Great work.